# Open/Save File Dialog

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, file, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

It's well known that class File has methods browseForOpen() and browseForSave().
The method browseForSave has built-in testing whether the file already exists. I don't need this testing and use browseForOpen for saving too. How can I change text "Open" to "Save" in
open file dialog (or how can I remove testing in save file dialog)?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. File open or save dialog comes from operating system or Flash Player and you can't modify it (if you could it would be a very big security hole of FP).